# new operator (Error :expected expression before struct)

Tags: c++, new-operator

```
struct node* NewNode(int data)
{
  struct node* node = new(struct node);
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  return(node);
}
```

I am getting this error in first line of the function. Cant figure out whats wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Its C++ only. I tried doing it like Struct node* node=new node, that is also giving error.

Comment: The way you have written it is unconventional, but legal.  You should edit your post to include the actual error you are receiving, as well as the definition of `struct node`.

Comment: What compiler (include version please)?  Can you provide enough code to be a complete file that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Have you tried node* node = new node; ie, without both of the struct's in the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code compiles perfectly fine under [Comeau try-it-out](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/):

```
#define NULL 0

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* NewNode(int data)
{
  struct node* node = new(struct node);
  node->data = data;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  return(node);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "new" keyword hints at this being C++. In C++ the "struct TYPENAME" construct is largely obsolete, you can simply use TYPENAME instead.
The C way of typedefing a type name from a named struct is implicit in C++.

```
node* NewNode(int data)
{
  node* pnode = new node;
  pnode->data = data;
  pnode->left = NULL;
  pnode->right = NULL;
  return(pnode);
}
```

should work just fine *if* this is C++. Please note that using the same name for a type and a variable is not a good idea. Some naming convention (hungarian or anything) helps.

Comment: +1 - but that `pnode` for a local variable is a bit odd in C++. Hungarian makes sense in C, but not really in C++, unless you write C-that-compiles-in-C++ style code. A 'p' prefix is much more likely to denote a parameter than a pointer in C++ - a convention that also exists in C.

Comment: That's why I wrote "hungarian or anything". Having a consistent naming convention in C++ also helps readility. And it doesn't really matter _which_ convention you pick as long as you stick to it.